# Async Refresh LVWP on load with HTML Form Param

Tags: 2010, javascript, filter, list-view-web-part, html-form-web-part

I have a List View WebPart that I need to asynchronously take a parameter from an HTML form WebPart and update the LVWP. I have some odd behavior happen when I attempt this. I have Async Load, Update, & manual refresh set to true for the LVWP. I have connected the HTML Form web part to the LVWP.

If I synchronously submit the HTML Form, the filter works as expected. I can also then submit the form with an Async Manual Refresh, and it works as expected. The issue I am facing is that on the initial load of the page an Async Manual Refresh of the list is NOT filtering results.

**Async Function**

```
__doPostBack(ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_<{WebPartID}>$ctl02","cancel")
```

Again, this function works as expected after 1 synchronous submission but not without one. Anyone seen this before?

**Update**

This is exactly what I am trying to do but with no luck...

[Filter SharePoint list with Partial Postback to page](http://dcsharepointchick.blogspot.com/2013/05/filter-sharepoint-list-with-partial-postback.html)

Comment: have you tried using a different approach? I've triggered the manual refresh before using the image inside the a $("#ManualRefresh").click() before with much success.

Comment: If I click the `ManualRefresh` img without first synchronously submitting, the manual refresh doesn't work.I need to be able to filter the LVWP initially without synchronously submitting.